# how to change an if statement to a switch

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, switch-statement

how to change the following code from an if statement to a switch. is it possible to increment the speed[0] according to the sequence showing below(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) 
the variable node is of a type object.

```
if (node->speed[0] > system->velocity)
    node->speed[0] = pSystem->velocity;
else if (node->speed[0] < pSystem->nVelocity)
    node->speed[0] = pSystem->nVelocity;
if (node->speed[1] > pSystem->velocity)
    node->speed[1] = pSystem->velocity;
else if (node->speed[1] < pSystem->nVelocity)
    node->speed[1] = pSystem->nVelocity;
if (node->speed[2] > pSystem->velocity)
    node->speed[2] = pSystem->velocity;
else if (node->speed[2] < pSystem->nVelocity)
    node->speed[2] = pSystem->nVelocity;
```

Comment: switch, I don't thinks so, but a for loop could help.

Comment: okay how to use the for loop, is there anyway to make the code better

Comment: you can't use this for switch statements. Thanks for asking us to tell you how to do something that is not possible

Answer (score 1):

There's no meaningful way to make a `switch` on comparisons, but I would rewrite that something like this (assuming that your "system" in the first line should actually be "pSystem"):

```
int clamp(int x, int min, int max)
{
    if (x < min)
        return min;
    if (x > max)
        return max;
    return x;
}

for (int i = 0; i<3 ; ++i)
  node->speed[i] = clamp(node->speed[i], pSystem->nVelocity, pSystem->velocity);
```

Side note: It looks like you've switched the meanings of "speed" and "velocity".
Velocity is a vector and has a direction and a magnitude, while speed is a scalar - the velocity's magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't really fit a switch statement, but a for loop fits.

```
for (int i = 0; i<3 ; ++i)
  if (node->speed[i] > system->velocity)
     node->speed[i] = pSystem->velocity;
  else if (node->speed[i] < pSystem->nVelocity)
     node->speed[i] = pSystem->nVelocity;
```

Comment: The OP's code has `system` only once, and `pSystem` eleven times. Only the OP can tell us if this is intentional or a misprint.